# How to pass parameters in a query in report those are linked to each other

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to use input controls in my report dashboard. I have 3 filters to apply. What I want to do is when I choose a date from the date filter the other filter must show the customers for that date only and when I select a customer then in third drop down list for third filter must show transactions carried out by that customer only.

In addition to these The dash board must display data for 'All' values in all the filters.
So that the user can view data for all transactions for all dates, all customers and also can select a particular date, customer and transaction

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to put parameters in the SQL queries, e.g you need to put a date_param in the second query(customers), then you need to put a cust_param in the transactional query. Before that you need to define those params in the designer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cascading input parameters.

What is cascading parameters?

In cascading parameters the list of values for one parameter depends on the value chosen
    in preceding parameter.

Order is important for cascading parameters because the dataset query for a parameter later in the list includes references to parameters earlier in the list.

For example suppose we have two input controls and names are Shipcountry and Shipcity, In this condition if we select Shipcountry then next input control Shipcity should show only those cities which belongs to that selected Shipping country.

You can refer this post for more detail [Creating cascading input controls](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2013/05/cascading-input-control.html)

You can add three input control p_date(DataType:Date), p_customer(Collection) and p_transaction(Collection), after adding parameters add condition in where clause of your query.

```
 Where date_columns = $P{p_date}
   AND $X{IN, customer,p_customer}
   AND $X{IN, transaction,p_transaction}
```

Then create three input controls in JasperReport server with where clause in the query of 2nd and 3rd input controls.